# Value of rational functions at a point

Tags: functions

Q is a rational function with $x \cdot Q(x+2018) = (x-2018)Q(x), \forall x \notin 2018 \text { and } 0$. If $Q(1) = 1$. what is $Q(2017)$?

I tried substituting values in for $Q(x)$ but there is no way to have both $Q(1)$ and $Q(2017)$ in the same equation, perhaps im missing a property of a rational function since i haven't used it yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $F(x) = xQ(x+2018)$, then $F(x) = F(x-2018)$. Hence $F$ is a periodic rational function and therefore $F$ is constant. If $F(x) = c$, then we have:

$$xQ(x+2018)=c\rightarrow Q(x+2018)=\frac{c}{x}\rightarrow Q(x)=\frac{c}{x-2018}$$

From $Q(1)=1$ we get $c= -2017$, hence $Q(x) = 2017/(2018-x)$; in particular, $Q(2017) = 2017$.

Answer (score 1):

By cross-dividing, we get:

$$\frac{x}{x-2018}=\frac{Q(x)}{Q(x+2018)}$$

Then, since $Q$ is rational, we say that $Q(x)=\frac{n(x)}{d(x)}$ where $n,d$ are polynomials. Thus, we get:

$$\frac{x}{x-2018}=\frac{\frac{n(x)}{d(x)}}{\frac{n(x+2018)}{d(x+2018)}}=\frac{n(x)d(x+2018)}{n(x+2018)d(x)}$$

Now, just kind of by guessing and checking, I see that if $n(x)=C$, where $C$ is a constant, and $d(x)=x-2018$, then we have a solution to the above equation. Thus, we have:

$$Q(x)=\frac{C}{x-2018} \text{ (maybe)}$$

Now, if $Q(x)=1$, then $\frac{C}{1-2018}=1\rightarrow C=-2017$. Thus:

$$Q(2017)=\frac{-2017}{2017-2018}=2017$$

Now, this does not prove that the only answer is $2017$ since there might be other possible functions for $Q(x)$ which I haven't considered. However, $2017$ is definitely one of the possible values of $Q(2017)$. I hope this helps!